# Как в behave использовать кириллицу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли в behave на python использовать кириллицу?

Столкнулся с проблемой когда в `.feature` файле использую кириллицу:

Пример фичи:

```
Scenario Outline: get goods by detailid 
Given тест <detailid>
```

Пример степа:

```
@given('тест {detailid}')
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

@given(u'тест 225444')
```

В `.feature` файле пробовал прописывать кодировку `# coding:utf8`, но не помогло.

Если использую латиницу, то проблем не возникает.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы уверены, что Питон 3 используете? Попробуйте u префикс добавить как сообщение об ошибке рекомендует.

Comment: Да, уверен что у меня Питон 3. В степе пробовал добавлять 'u, не помогло.
'@given(u'тест {detailid}')'

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен русский язык, можно переписать feature-файл полностью на русском.

```
# language: ru
Функционал: Бьет ли Пикачу молнией

  Сценарий: Идет дождь

    Дано Выполнен переход на сайт 'пикачу.поражений.net'
    Тогда Выполнен переход в Пикачу 'Маркет'
    И Выбран раздел 'Обувь'
    И Выбран тип 'Резиновые сапоги'
```